"Topologically Trivial Legendrian Knot" - Trouble understanding it
I'm reading the Eliashberg and Fraser's work: "Topologically Trivial Legendrian Knot", that can be found online on Archive. I've pretty much understood everything about it. I've only a problem with the Lemma 1.3. It proves that two diffeomorphic Legendrian trees are necessarily isotopic. The proofs contains the following phrase:
By the assumption there is a (germ of a) diffeomorphism $h \colon \Pi \to \Pi$ which sends $\tilde{L}'$ into $\tilde{L}$. One can assume that $h$ is fixed at the
points of the projection of $L'_1$, preserves the area form $dx\wedge dy$, and is isotopic to the identity in the space of diffeomorphisms with these properties.
I know that maybe this is not the correct way of asking a question, but I'm pretty much out of luck of understanding this passage. And since the work is basis for my master thesis, I cannot just ignore it.
So: is there somebody that has read the article, and that has a better understanding of this passage? For starting, I have no clue what is intended with "(germ of a) diffeomorphism", and why should be an endofuncion from $\Pi$ to itself.

Just a suggestion: you could try sending an email to the authors

Yea, I've tried some weeks ago, but probably was not a good period. I was thinking of trying again these days. I wanted to try with skatckexchange first

Can you explain what it is you do not understand about these sentences? is it "germ of a differmorphism"? Is it why $h$ can be assumed to fix the projection, why it can be assummed to preserve the area form, why it is isotopic to the identity?

@PaulSinclair Yea sorry, the question was a bit to concise. Here is more clarification:


I don't get why h can suppose to fix to projection. If I consider a generic diffeomorphism g : M -> M, and i restrict it to some open U, then g|_U cannot be supposed to be an endomorfism from U to itself.


why can we suppose that preserves the area form?


every diffeomorphism (orien. preserving) of the plane is isotopic to the identity. IF the plane had been compact, then through Moser Trick I can suppose that the isotopy is made of symplectomorphism. Maybe I can do it by passing to $S^2$?


